# what are workspace variables in java Eclipse? How to create them?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, workspace

What are work space variables in java Eclipse? How to create them?
I need to create some workspace variables.
Are these the normal variables of Java?

Comment: Do you mean program arguments from run configuration?

Comment: It is not arguments.It is workspace variable with variable name as MM_Fusing_Forlm.I have no idea what is meant by workspace variable.

Comment: Can you more provide more information about what you are doing as it is unclear what you mean.

Comment: run configurations is the properties file u are mentioning?

Answer (score 1):

Go to preferences->Run/Debug->String Substitution and add new variables.
Predefined like workspace_loc are not here, you have to edit them in ur run configurations only.